# Multiple C# projects in the same root directory

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a root directory with multiple C# projects (*.csproj).
I need MSBuild to filter the C# source files by root namespace for each project, since they share the same root directory.
Otherwise, I will get `error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined` when I try to run a project using `dotnet run --project Project1.csproj`.
My project folder structure is organized based on features, and test files are included inside the feature sub-folders.

Sample solution structure:

```
|_ Project1.csproj
|_ Project2.csproj
|_ Program1.cs (this contains main for Project1 under root namespace P1)
|_ Program2.cs (this contains main for Project2 under root namespace P2)
|_ Feature1 (this feature belongs to Project1 under root namespace P1)
|  |_ SomeClass1.cs
|  |_ SomeClass1.test.cs
|_ Feature2 (this feature belongs to Project2 under root namespace P2)
   |_ SomeClass2.cs
   |_ SomeClass2.test.cs
```

Now, how can I run/build Project1.csproj such that MSBuild will only include Program1.cs and SomeClass1.cs. Similar thing with Project2.csproj with Program2.cs and SomeClass2.cs. Can I ask MSBuild to include only files/types based on their root namespace?

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: You need to have projects inside their respective directories... `Solution (folder) -> Project1 (folder) -> Project1.csproj, Program1.cs` and `Solution (folder) -> Project2 (folder) -> Project2.csproj, Program2.cs`. Is not possible for you to achive this structure?

Comment: I want to structure the project based on features and have all source files from all projects (e.g. server, client, test) related to a feature inside its respective sub-folder.

Comment: That's when you make the things unnecessarily complex and error prone. You can create feature related folders inside Project Folder too and put the feature specific classes in those folders. .NET project structures are project and solution centric and you still organize your code and files according to features/layers.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion but that is not answering my question. At the end there is no right or wrong approach here and I am not intending to discuss the pros and cons. But if you know a way to achieve what I am asking of feature files locality then I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I have one question... the structure you shared  above is the solution structure you see in the VS Solution Explorer? Can you also share physical folder structure of your solution?

Comment: The above solution structure is similar to what I have in reality. Multiple projects at the root directory with multiple entry points. That is why I need to filter what source files get into the build for each project, for example by specifying the root namespace for each project.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, what you do is not done correctly. Most likely you were trying to achieve something that could be achieved differently.

But here is a legit method to achieve what you're looking for.
In your `Project1.csproj` add `ItemGroup` like this

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Project2.csproj" />
  <None Remove="Program2.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Above is based on assumption that you have new project file format, where every file in the folder is auto-included into project. Vs old, framework format, were files explicitly listed inside the project file.

In fact, Microsoft now has section [Keep existing projects and create a .NET project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/project-structure#keep-existing-projects-and-create-a-net-project)

Comment: Hi T.S. I get this error when I try to `dotnet run --project Project1.csproj` in the terminal: `Program1.cs(7,21): error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.`

Comment: Also, do I need to have a remove tag for each and every file from the other projects or only the project and entry class files?

Comment: @geeko it is telling you that you have multiple `void Main(string[] atgs)`. You should only have 1 and if you have more `ProgramX.cs`, you need to list all so msbuild ignores them

Comment: I need to have multiple entry points because there are multiple projects (e.g. server, client, test). That is why I need to filter what source files get into the build for each project, for example by specifying a root namespace for each project. Do you know of any way to do it?

Comment: Though, each project has absolutely one entry point which I am trying to run using `dotnet run --project Project1.csproj`

Comment: @geeko the problem is that if you don't add `Remove`, when `csproj` file is found, it is still attempted to process. So, you basically need to add these `Remove` instructions to every proj file and exclude anything that is not related to it. So, here we are back to position #1 - your idea of having these together is a wrong idea. If you want to build specific features, you can do it via Solution Configurations, conditional compilation and partial classes. But each project folder should contain only fileset that belongs to that project.

Comment: An idea is not wrong just because it is currently impossible to implement or we do not know how to implement it. I just found a way to specify the entry point for each project `<StartupObject>Project1.Program</StartupObject>`. I just need now to check how to exclude source files from the build using root namespaces or some similar way.

Comment: @geeko you can't use namespaces during compilation time. Namespaces organize types, not files. The only way to do it on the code level is conditional compilation

Comment: Thank you T.S. So, what you are saying is that there is no conditional compilation based on namespaces to exclude irrelevant types from a project build. May be if I use a convention on source file names, I will be able to achieve this using file names.

Comment: @geeko There are multiple possibilities. Conditional compilation is when you have compilation arguments and in code `#if arg1 #then <any code> #end if`.. Then you can have build configuration and explicit file include `<None Include="some file" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'BuildForSomething' ">` See this https://markheath.net/post/csproj-conditional-references